# How do send a random number of OTP in flutter without using firebase?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_otp/flutter_otp.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}


class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String countryCode = "+44";
  String phoneNumber = "xxxxxxxxxx"//enter phone number;
  int minNumber = 1000;
  int maxNumber = 6000;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("send otp using flutter_otp ")),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Send"),
          onPressed: () {
            FlutterOtp().sendOtp(
              phoneNumber,
              countryCode,
              minNumber,
              maxNumber,
            );
           
          },
        )),
      ),
    );``
  }
}
```

This code sends me the country code as an OTP. How do I send a random number as the OTP.Are there any other plugins available for sending an OTP using flutter (without using firebase)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this snippet to make random String / OTP

```
import 'dart:math' as math;


  String chars =
      'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
  math.Random rnd = math.Random();

  String getRandomString(int length) => String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
      length, (_) => chars.codeUnitAt(rnd.nextInt(chars.length))));
```